# Showing a DataGridViewColumn in the DataGridView column type picker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am working on a `C#` `WinForms` project that was using a large number of `DataGridView`s. Because I needed some custom functionality, I have extended the `DataGridViewColumn` into a class called `ExtendedDGVColumn`. I want to be able to select it when adding/editing a `DataGridView`'s columns in the following screens:

[image: Add column screen]
[image: Edit column screen]

**How can I have my `ExtendedDGVColumn` appear in these two lists?**

Comment: I just tried that works for me. Are you sure your column class in `public` ? otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Ahhh it wasn't. That did it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView designer is good enough to find your *custom columns* and show it in the dropdown. It will not consider a column(class) is it is not declared as `public`.

Make sure you have the class declared as `public`. That should work.